# React: Change deeply nested state optimisation

Tags: reactjs, state, immutability, nested-datalist

I come up with a solution for change the properties in a second level nested state in React that is not scalable and it doesn't seem quite efficient. How can you do a refactor of `handleOnChange` method in order to change `reps` and `weight`?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const workout = {
  id: "123-234sdf-1213",
  name: "wo name",
  done: false,
  exercises: [
    {
      name: "back squat",
      sets: [
        {
          number: 0,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false,
        },
        {
          number: 1,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false,
        },
        {
          number: 2,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "leg press",
      sets: [
        {
          number: 0,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false,
        },
        {
          number: 1,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false,
        },
        {
          number: 2,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

export default function App() {
  const [workoutState, setWorkoutState] = useState(workout);

  const handleOnChange = (e, exIndex, setIndex) => {
    const value = e.target.value ? parseFloat(e.target.value) : "";
    const exercises = [...workoutState.exercises];

    exercises[exIndex].sets[setIndex] = {
      ...exercises[exIndex].sets[setIndex],
      [e.target.name]: value,
    };
    setWorkoutState({
      ...workoutState,
      exercises,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{workoutState.name}</h1>
      {workoutState.exercises.map((ex, exIndex) => (
        <>
          <h2>{ex.name}</h2>
          {ex.sets.map((set, setIndex) => (
            <div key={`${ex.name}_${setIndex}`}>
              <div>
                reps:{" "}
                <input
                  value={set.reps}
                  name="reps"
                  type="number"
                  onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e, exIndex, setIndex)}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                weight:{" "}
                <input
                  value={set.weight}
                  name="weight"
                  type="number"
                  onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e, exIndex, setIndex)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you are on the right track with how you want to update the nested state, but you do have a state mutation in your current `handleOnChange` implementation. You are mutating `exercises[exIndex]`.

```
const handleOnChange = (e, exIndex, setIndex) => {
  const value = e.target.value ? parseFloat(e.target.value) : "";
  const exercises = [...workoutState.exercises];

  exercises[exIndex].sets[setIndex] = { // <-- mutates exercises[exIndex]
    ...exercises[exIndex].sets[setIndex],
    [e.target.name]: value,
  };
  setWorkoutState({
    ...workoutState,
    exercises,
  });
};
```

You should shallow copy each nested level of state you intend to update.

I recommend using functional state updates so if for *any reason* more than a single state update is enqueued during a render cycle the update will work from the previous update versus from using the state from the render cycle the update was enqueued.

I also prefer making the handler a curried function. It takes the indices as arguments and returns a function that consumes the `onChange` event object. This allows you to remove the anonymous function declaration and need to proxy the event object yourself when attaching the handler, i.e. `onChange={handleOnChange(exIndex, setIndex)}` versus `onChange={e => handleOnChange(e, exIndex, setIndex)}`

```
const handleOnChange = (eIndex, sIndex) => e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;

  setWorkoutState((workoutState) => ({
    ...workoutState,
    exercises: workoutState.exercises.map((exercise, exerciseIndex) =>
      exerciseIndex === eIndex
        ? {
            ...exercise,
            sets: exercise.sets.map((set, setIndex) =>
              setIndex === sIndex
                ? {
                    ...set,
                    [name]: Number(value)
                  }
                : set
            )
          }
        : exercise
    )
  }));
};
```

The inputs. I added a `step` attribute and attach the curried handler. I also placed each input in a `label` element for accessibility; you can click the label and focus the field.

```
<div>
  <label>
    reps:{" "}
    <input
      value={set.reps}
      name="reps"
      step={1}
      type="number"
      onChange={handleOnChange(exIndex, setIndex)}
    />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    weight:{" "}
    <input
      value={set.weight}
      name="weight"
      step={0.1}
      type="number"
      onChange={handleOnChange(exIndex, setIndex)}
    />
  </label>
</div>
```

[image: Edit react-change-deeply-nested-state-optimisation]

Full code:

```
const workout = {
  id: "123-234sdf-1213",
  name: "wo name",
  done: false,
  exercises: [
    {
      name: "back squat",
      sets: [
        {
          number: 0,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false
        },
        {
          number: 1,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false
        },
        {
          number: 2,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "leg press",
      sets: [
        {
          number: 0,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false
        },
        {
          number: 1,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false
        },
        {
          number: 2,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          done: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

export default function App() {
  const [workoutState, setWorkoutState] = useState(workout);

  const handleOnChange = (eIndex, sIndex) => (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setWorkoutState((workoutState) => ({
      ...workoutState,
      exercises: workoutState.exercises.map((exercise, exerciseIndex) =>
        exerciseIndex === eIndex
          ? {
              ...exercise,
              sets: exercise.sets.map((set, setIndex) =>
                setIndex === sIndex
                  ? {
                      ...set,
                      [name]: Number(value)
                    }
                  : set
              )
            }
          : exercise
      )
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{workoutState.name}</h1>
      {workoutState.exercises.map((ex, exIndex) => (
        <>
          <h2>{ex.name}</h2>
          {ex.sets.map((set, setIndex) => (
            <div key={`${ex.name}_${setIndex}`}>
              <h3>Set {setIndex}</h3>
    <div>
      <label>
        reps:{" "}
        <input
          value={set.reps}
          name="reps"
          step={1}
          type="number"
          onChange={handleOnChange(exIndex, setIndex)}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        weight:{" "}
        <input
          value={set.weight}
          name="weight"
          step={0.1}
          type="number"
          onChange={handleOnChange(exIndex, setIndex)}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: but it seems that i cannot delete de first 0

Comment: Hi @DavideCariani Can you clarify a bit what you mean that you "cannot delete [the] first 0? Are you referring to the default reps/weight values in your `workout.exercies` arrays?

Comment: hey @DrewReese, yes I mean that is not possible to delete the first 0. In the sandbox you can see it.

Comment: @DavideCariani Ah, ok, in `setWorkoutState` if you change `[name]: Number(value)` to `[name]: value` you can backspace from a "0" back to an empty string in the inputs.